Unauthorized Error while using CLoud Config Spring Security and Eureka together
I have been trying to run my Eureka server and Cloud config together, I'm using Spring Boot 3.1.3 and Spring Cloud version 2022.0.5. Since a lot of things get deprecated I updated my code and got Unauthorized Error:
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 : "{"timestamp":"2024-04-01T11:58:53.982+00:00","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","path":"/eureka-server/default"}"
My Cloud Config is working perfectly, and tried everything from last 5 days.
Things I have tried:

added org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
dependency
change config server application.yml configuration
Tried to remove config server dependency and tried running Eureka server in
local to check security-related issues No luck.

Need help with it.
Config-server/SpringConfig.java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig{
    @Value("${spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri}")
    String cloudLocation;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(cloudLocation + "-------------------------------" );
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}

Config-server/application.yml
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: D:\Learning\config-repo
          cloneOnStart: true
  security:
    user:
      name: root
      password: root
  activate:
    on-profile: native
# WARNING: Exposing all management endpoints over http should only be used during development, must be locked down in production!
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  security:
    enabled: false

logging:
  level:
    root: info

Eureka-server/SecurityConfig.java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(
            @Value("${spring.security.user.name}") String username,
            @Value("${spring.security.user.password}") String password
    ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        System.out.println("UseName---------" + username + "Password-----------" + password);
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return  http
                .csrf(cs -> cs.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}

Eureka-server/application.yml
spring.config.import: "configserver:http://localhost:8888"

spring:
  application.name: eureka-server
  security:
    user:
      name: root
      password: root
  cloud.config:
    failFast: true
    retry:
      initialInterval: 3
      multiplier: 1.3
      maxInterval: 10
      maxAttempts: 20
    uri: http://localhost:8888
    username: ${CONFIG_SERVER_USR}
    password: ${CONFIG_SERVER_PWD}
management:
  security:
    enabled: false

Config Repository : https://github.com/kakarot987/config-repo


After so many tries, I fixed this issue just by modifying Config-server/SecurityConfig.java file
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(cloudLocation + "-------------------------------" );
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                


.httpBasic(ht -> ht.disable())

                .build();
    }

